# Read matlab file (*.mat) from zipped file without extracting to directory in Python

Tags: python, matlab, zip

This specific questions stems from the attempt to handle large data sets produced by a MATLAB algorithm so that I can process them with python algorithms.

**Background:** I have large arrays in MATLAB (typically 20x20x40x15000 [i,j,k,frame]) and I want to use them in python. So I save the array to a *.mat file and use `scipy.io.loadmat(fname)` to read the *.mat file into a numpy array. However, a problem arises in that if I try to load the entire *.mat file in python, a memory error occurs. To get around this, I slice the *.mat file into pieces, so that I can load the pieces one at a time into a python array. If I divide up the *.mat by frame, I now have 15,000 *.mat files which quickly becomes a pain to work with (at least in windows). So my solution is to use zipped files.

**Question:** Can I use scipy to directly read a *.mat file from a zipped file without first unzipping the file to the current working directory?

**Specs:** Python 2.7, windows xp

**Current code:**

```
import scipy.io
import zipfile
import numpy as np

def readZip(zfilename,dim,frames):
    data=np.zeros((dim[0],dim[1],dim[2],frames),dtype=np.float32)
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile( zfilename, "r" )
    i=0
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        fname = info.filename
        zfile.extract(fname)
        mat=scipy.io.loadmat(fname)
        data[:,:,:,i]=mat['export']
        mat.clear()
        i=i+1
    return data
```

**Tried code:**

```
mat=scipy.io.loadmat(zfile.read(fname))
```

*produces this error:*

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

---

```
mat=scipy.io.loadmat(zfile.open(fname))
```

*produces this error:*

```
fileobj.seek(0)
UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

---

Any other suggestions on handling the data are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to read the whole file upfront? Can you unzip it and process on the fly?

Comment: @matcheek, I guess I could, however, I prefer the array to be in memory so then I can use various algorithms on the array and generate animations with vtk.

Comment: Your code indicates the whole array fits in memory i.e., only loading procedure causes `MemoryError`. Have you enable the compression of mat-file in matlab?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have not tried that, I wonder if scipy supports it

Comment: @Onlyjus: It should (at least the source suggests it). Other options: - extract the file, but delete it immediately after loading; - save using HDF5 format (matlab 7.3) and load with `h5py` or `PyTables`

Comment: @Onlyjus: have you considered splitting the frames in batches, say every 1000 frames in one MAT-file. That way each matrix will be of size `20*20*40*1000*8 / 2^20 = 122 MB` in memory (assuming `double` type). Also you should know that new [MAT-file formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html#inputarg_version) supports compression natively, so no need for zipping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the answer to my question is **NO** and there are better ways to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Regardless, with the suggestion from J.F. Sebastian, I have devised a solution.

**Solution:** Save the data in MATLAB in the HDF5 format, namely `hdf5write(fname, '/data', data_variable)`. This produces a *.h5 file which then can be read into python via [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/).

**python code:**

```
import h5py

r = h5py.File(fname, 'r+')
data = r['data']
```

I can now index directly into the data, however is stays on the hard drive.

```
print data[:,:,:,1]
```

Or I can load it into memory.

```
data_mem = data[:]
```

However, this once again gives memory errors. So, to get it into memory I can loop through each frame and add it to a numpy array.

h5py FTW!

Answer (score 0):

In one of my frozen applications we bundle some files into the .bin file that py2exe creates, then pull them out like this:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(myDir, 'common.bin'))

data = z.read('schema-new.sql')
```

I am not certain if that would feed your .mat files into scipy, but I'd consider it worth a try.

Comment: I tired using 'data=z.read(fname)' and 'data=z.open(fname)', however 'scipy.io.loadmat(data)' has fit since data is a 'str'